# TypeError: undefined is not an object using d3.map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, undefined

I am getting an "[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'm.get("foo").name')" error that I do not understand at all. The code is taken directly from the d3js API page and works when I try it on jsfiddle, but on my computer it doesn't work.

Here is the full code:

```
    var m = d3.map([{name: "foo"}, {name: "bar"}], function(d) { return d.name; });
    console.log(m.get("foo").name);
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I've tried this on both Safari and Chrome, I get the same results.

Comment: Perhaps a JSFiddle would be beneficial ?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a misunderstanding of the `map` method. It should be applied directly to your object, and not called on the `d3` one. For example:

```
var S=[{name: "foo"}, {name: "bar"}];
var m = S.map(function(d) { return d.name; });
console.log(m);
```

This will return the object:

```
["foo","bar"]
```

If you are thinking of creating an assosiative multi-dimensional array, perhaps you could use the `d3.nest()` method like here:

```
var S=[{name: "foo", "coolvalue":5}, {name: "bar", "coolvalue":15}];
var w=d3.nest().key(function(d){return d.name}).map(S);
console.log(w['foo'][0].coolvalue);
```

This will output 5.

Of course it all depends on what you want to achieve in the end.

Hope this helps